# ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'persistsecurity info' .NET Core MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm getting the exception

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'persistsecurity info'

when attempting to read to the database after upgrading from .NET Core 1.1 to .NET Core 2.0. Project is using .NET Core MVC Framework with EF Core.

**Appsettings.json**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnection": "Server=tcp: server.address, 1433;Initial Catalog=SmartDB;PersistSecurity Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SmartDBConnection")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the argument is supposed to be `Persist Security Info` or `PersistSecurityInfo`, not `PersistSecurity Info` with just one space.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! But out of curiosity was this changed with .NET Core 2.0? Because it previously worked on .NET Core 1.1

Answer (score 1):

It should be `Persist Security Info` so updated connection string would be,

```
 "DBConnection": "Server=tcp: server.address, 1433;Initial Catalog=SmartDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

`